# Next.js 14 JWT Session Error with Next Auth - type error

Tags: typescript, next.js, jwt, next-auth, next.js14

I've been playing around with Next.js 14 with Next Auth 5 beta and whenever I try to log in, I get the
[auth][error][JWTSessionError]
[auth][cause]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username'). I've actually been following a tutorial which made it work because it didn't user TypeScript, but I work as a developer so I need to use TS.

Here is my auth.ts:

```
import "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { connectDb } from "./lib/utils";
import { User } from "./lib/models";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { UserType } from "./lib/types";
import NextAuth, { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user: UserType;
  }
}

declare module "@auth/core/types" {
  interface Session {
    user: UserType;
  }
}

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface User {
    username: string;
    img: string;
  }
}

const login = async (credentials: Partial<Record<string, unknown>>) => {
  try {
    connectDb();
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: credentials.username });

    if (!user) throw new Error("Invalid credentials");

     const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
       credentials.password as string,
       user.password
    );

    if (!isPasswordCorrect) throw new Error("Invalid credentials");

    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error("Login failed");
  }
};

export const authConfig: NextAuthConfig = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const user = await login(credentials);
          return user;
        } catch (error) {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request }) {
      const isLoggedIn = auth?.user;
      const isOnDashboard = request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard");
      if (isOnDashboard) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true;
        return false;
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", request.nextUrl));
      }
      return true;
    },
    async session({ session, user }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.username = user.username;
        session.user.img = user.img;
      }
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.username = user.username || "someUsername";
        token.img = user.img || "";
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
};

export const { signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth(authConfig);
```

And here is the screenshot of the error:
[image]

I've been able to verify that the user has been successfully found and downloaded and that the username and img have been appended to the token by using console log. So I'm not sure what else I could do. Please help.

WIP repo: https://github.com/CzechCoder/dashboard_next/tree/main

Answer (score 0):

you are using "Next Auth 5" but your configuration is for v4. in v5 it is used like this:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signOut,
  signIn,
  update,
} = NextAuth({
  adapter: // if you are using adapter,

  providers: [
    // add providers here 
  ],
  callbacks: {
   // add callbacks here
  },
});
```

Please follow the [upgrade-to-v5 guide](https://authjs.dev/guides/upgrade-to-v5)